# Binding list in RadGridView

Tags: wpf, telerik, telerik-grid, radgridview

I am using Telerik RadGridView to display dynamic data, stored in classes like bellow:

```
public class Field
{
    public string FieldName{ get; set; }
    public string FieldValue{ get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    public List<Field> Fields{ get; set; }

    public Row()
    {
        Fields= new List<Field>();
    }
}
```

A Row has "n" Fields.
I need to display each "Row" in a line in the grid and each Field like a column in the line.

When I set:

```
myGrid.ItemSource = myList;
```

I get something like this:

```
Fields
--------------------
(Collection)
(Collection)
...
```

When I really need is a table like this:

```
Name        Gender    Date ...
----------- --------- --------
JOHN        M         10/10/2010
PETER ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just resolve this problems using DataSet native objects, like this example:

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/gridview/binding-radgridview-to-datatable-and-adding-items-to-datatable.aspx